# Arbitrage between gamma and delta on smaller timescale in options selling

Tags: options, greeks, index, option-strategies, short-selling

I have observed that sometimes (mostly for OTM options) near expiration, an increase in option price cannot be fully explained by delta and theta(given volatility is constant). The gamma spiked the premiums especially during intraday moves. Causing a mini arbitrage between the options Greeks as theta would have to embody all the gamma exposure once the index moves halt, is there a way to go gamma short and possibly hedge the position for volatility?